# Make input box with predefined Value

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to create an input box which already has a predefined value in the textfield ?

Preferred way whould be `Read-Host`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with `Read-Host`, but you could still do it from Powershell by using the underlying .NET classes as follows:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$Value = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Value", "Test", "Default Value")
```